# How do I select only one div between a group of divs like a radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have group of divs:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 well bb paylater" value="paylater" onclick="selectPayment(this)">payment1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 well bb alipay" value="alipay" onclick="selectPayment(this)">payment2</div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 well bb wechatpay" value="wechatpay" onclick="selectPayment(this)">payment3</div>
        </div>
```

My JS:

```
function appendCheckMark(type) {
            $(type).append('<span class="label label-info payment_select"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>');
        }


        function selectPayment(type) {
            var val = $(type).attr('value');
            if ( val == 'paylater') {
                appendCheckMark(type);

            }
            else if (val == 'alipay') {
                appendCheckMark(type);

            }
            else if (val == 'wechatpay'){
                appendCheckMark(type);

            }
        }
```

My question is, how do I make those three div like a radio button? So a user can only select one of them?

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: add and remove class directly to the divs use css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply remove first the existing  payment_select span before appending a new one.

```
function selectPayment(type) {
   //remove existing check here
   $(type).parent().find('.payment_select').remove();
   var val = $(type).attr('value');
   if ( val == 'paylater') {
        appendCheckMark(type);

   }
   else if (val == 'alipay') {
       appendCheckMark(type);

    }
    else if (val == 'wechatpay'){
       appendCheckMark(type);

    }
}
```

Comment: `function selectPayment(type) {
    //remove existing check here
    $(type).parent().find('.payment_select').remove();
    var val = $(type).attr('value');
    if (val == 'paylater' || val == 'alipay' || val == 'wechatpay') {
        appendCheckMark(type);
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, just remove the appended div while click on any div.

```
function appendCheckMark(type) {
    $(type).append('<span class="label label-info payment_select"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>');
  }


  function selectPayment(type) {

            $('.payment_select').remove();
            var val = $(type).attr('value');
            if ( val == 'paylater') {
                appendCheckMark(type);
            }
            else if (val == 'alipay') {
                appendCheckMark(type);
            }
            else if (val == 'wechatpay'){
                appendCheckMark(type);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the div when it is clicked and handle the look of that div using css.

```
function selectPayment(type) {
        var val = $(type).attr('value');
        $(type).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected')
        if ( val == 'paylater') {
            appendCheckMark(type);

        }
        else if (val == 'alipay') {
            appendCheckMark(type);

        }
        else if (val == 'wechatpay'){
            appendCheckMark(type);

        }
```

There, you have the selected div with class selected and others don't have that class. Use css for changing the aesthetic.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move existent check mark into new location. No need to remove anything and reappend again:

```js
function appendCheckMark(type) {
    var $check = $('.payment_select').length ? $('.payment_select') : $('<span class="label label-info payment_select"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>');
    $(type).append($check);
}

function selectPayment(type) {
    var val = $(type).attr('value');
    appendCheckMark(type);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 well bb paylater" value="paylater" onclick="selectPayment(this)">payment1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 well bb alipay" value="alipay" onclick="selectPayment(this)">payment2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 well bb wechatpay" value="wechatpay" onclick="selectPayment(this)">payment3</div>
</div>
```